# Vim - how to start inserting at the end of the file in one step

Tags: vim

Is there a single shortcut to start inserting in the new line at end of the file?

I'm aware of <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> combo.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There's also the command line option "+":

```
vim + myfile.txt
```

Will open myfile.txt and do an automatic G for you.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't add a new line at the end of the file, and the questioner doesn't specify that it should be when opening the file.

Comment: @kenorb of course it doesn't, someone sabotaged my answer. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 19):

Not that I know of - <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is what I would have suggested too, but that is 2 steps :)

You could always create a macro which does <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, and then you can invoke the macro which will be 1 step.

Answer (score 12):

Adding the following into ~/.vimrc will create one for you:

```
:nmap ^A Go
```

To type the "^A" first press Ctrl-V, then press Ctrl-A. You can then use Ctrl-A to append at the end of the file when not in insert or visual mode.

Comment: Note that this overrides the default behavior of ^A, which is to increment the number or character under the cursor intelligently.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo >> myfile.txt && vim -c 'startinsert' + myfile.txt
```

You can also save the above command in a script and then use $1 instead of myfile.txt, name your script myvim ( or whatever you like ) and always open your files and start writing away instantly.

```
myvim myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stick the map definition in your .vimrc and then invoke it when the you open the file.

Or, if you only want to do this for a particular file, you could create an autocmd for that file type that does it automatically. See [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand) in the vim doc's.