# Vim: from command line, go to end of file and start editing?

Tags: command-line, vi

I can cause vim to position the cursor at the last line of a file by invoking it with an argument of `+`:

```
vi + myfile          # "+" = go to last line of file
```

How can I do this, and then go into append mode, so that the user can start typing at the end of the file?

Something similar to

```
emacs myfile --eval "(goto-char (point-max))"
```

Comment: hmm, I get:
Error detected while processing command line:
E20: Mark not set

Comment: does this work for you?  for me, it starts inserting at the first character of the first line, which is not what I want.  I need to go to the end of the file.

Comment: @TimBiegleisen, emacs works great.  this question is about doing the same thing in vim.

Comment: Read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268123/vim-how-to-start-inserting-at-the-end-of-the-file-in-one-step).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yeah, it's not working, as I mentioned.  This is vim 7.3 fwiw.

Comment: Maybe update your question with these specifics.  Sadly, I'm working in a Windows shop at the moment, so other than Cygwin (which won't help here), I do not have access to Vim on a Linux box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution could be to use the `+` parameter to pass a command to execute after reading the file. Vim can take up to 10 commands this way so you can use:

```
vim "+norm Go" "+startinsert" myfile
```

- The first command `norm Go` will go to the last line and add a new one.
- The second command will start insert mode allowing the user to type in the last line.

**Note** This solution creates a new line at the end of the file. If you want to edit the end of the last line without creating a new one you could use something like that :

```
vim "+norm G$" "+startinsert" myfile
```

**But** If you do this and your last line already contains some text, you will start inserting text before the last character. I don't know an equivalent to `startinsert` like `startappend` so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: The first one does exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Also you might be interested in the [Vi/ViM SE site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) for future questions about Vim :-)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to `startinsert` like `startappend` is `startinsert!` according to [this site](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/vim/commands/startinsert#:%7E:text=%EE%80%80Vim%EE%80%81%20ex%20command%3A%20%EE%80%80startinsert%EE%80%81.%20When%20%EE%80%80startinsert%EE%80%81%20is%20used,mark%29%20can%20be%20used.%20See%20also.%20Ex%20commands.). So the answer could be

```
vim "+norm G$" "+startinsert!" myfile
```